# Simple Mockito Test (Spring + Dao)

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am beyond frustrated because I can't figure this out. I've been over millions of articles and NOTHING is clear on how this is done. I am trying to write a Mockito test just for practice.

I have a spring java app which is getting data from a database.

Here is the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="Lookup" class="com.gd.test.Lookup">
    <property name="AssetClassDao" ref="assetClass" />
</bean>

<bean id="assetClass" class="com.gd.impl.AssetClassImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=test" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>
```

AssetClassDao.java

```
public interface AssetClassDao {

     public AssetClass getAssetDataById(int id);
}
```

AssetClassImpl.java

```
public class AssetClassImpl implements AssetClassDao {

private DataSource dataSource;
AssetClass ac = new AssetClass();

@Override
public AssetClass getAssetDataById(int id) {

    String sql = "select id, name from TABLE where id="
            + String.valueOf(id);

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            ac.setASSET_CLASS_ID(rs.getString("id"));
            ac.setASSET_CLASS_NAME(rs.getString("name"));
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        return ac;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ac;
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
}
```

Lookup.java

```
public class Lookup {

private AssetClassDao assetClassDao;

public void runNameLookup() throws IOException {

    AssetClass byOne = assetClassDao.getAssetDataById(5);

    System.out.println(byOne.toString());

}

public AssetClassDao getAssetClassDao() {
    return assetClassDao;
}

public void setAssetClassDao(AssetClassDao assetClassDao) {
    this.assetClassDao = assetClassDao;
}

}
```

The query returns "5" as the ID and "Mortgage" as the NAME. 
For my test that I am writing with Mockito, how does it know which implementation to use?

My test:

```
public class TestLookup {
@Mock
private AssetClassDao acd;

@Mock
private Lookup al;

@Mock
private AssetClass ac;

@Before
public void setupMock(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    acd = mock(AssetClassImpl.class);
}

@Test
public void testDataById(){
    when(acd.getAssetDataById(5)).thenReturn(ac);
    System.out.println(acd.getAssetDataById(5).getNAME());
}
}
```

How do I test these values properly?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing the following statements you are creating a new object of class `AssetClass`:

```
AssetClass ac = new AssetClass();
```

If you are using Spring then you should be injecting this as one of the dependencies as follows:

```
@Autowired
private AssetClass ac;
```

You can now mock this dependency out by writing the following in your test class:

```
@Mock
private AssetClass ac;
```

Also, you'll have to mock the other dependencies like `DataSource`, `Connection` etc. and do something like this:

```
@Mock
private DataSource dataSource;

@Mock
private Connection conn;

...

Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
```

I hope this will provide you some essence of Mockito and how to use it.

Comment: I didn't know I had to also mock the datasource and connection... gonna work on that now

Comment: @gd000 You should be mocking `DataSource`, `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` & `ResultSet` in addition to `AssetClass`.